# SwiftUI ActionSheet disabled button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-actionsheet

This seems like maybe a simple question, but I'm looking for a way to make one (or more, I suppose) buttons in an `ActionSheet` in SwiftUI to be disabled. For example, if something is illegal based on the state of the app, I don't want to let the user click the button - indeed, I might change the text to explain why it's disabled.

Xcode autocomplete isn't really turning anything up for me, and the docs ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/actionsheet/button) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert/button)) aren't giving me anything. Is my best/only option simply not putting the button in the list of buttons in the `ActionSheet`? (And kinda letting the user infer why it's not there...)

Thanks so much for any advice!

My simple code:

```
  private func getActionSheet() -> ActionSheet {

    let buttons: [ActionSheet.Button] = [
      .default(Text("This is fine...")) { foo() },
      .default(Text("This is forbidden - disable me!")) { foo() },
      .cancel()
    ]

    return ActionSheet(title: Text("Do it!"), buttons: buttons)
  }
```

Comment: Action sheets don't  have disabling. Why not just show a custom view? Or a menu?

Answer (score 1):

For nondestructive actions you can simply show a Menu. They support the `.disabled(true)` modifier.

```swift
 var body: some View {
    Menu("Do it!") {
        Button("This button works fine", action: { })
        
        Button("This one is disabled", action: { })
            .disabled(true)
    }
}
```